# Unexpected behaviour in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand the following odd behavior observed using the `python mutiprocessing`.

Sample testClass:
    import os
    import multiprocessing

```
class testClass(multiprocessing.Process):    

    def __del__(self):
        print "__del__ PID: %d" % os.getpid()
        print self.a    

    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        print "__init__ PID: %d" % os.getpid()
        self.a = 0    

    def run(self):
        print "method1 PID: %d" % os.getpid()
        self.a = 1
```

And a little test program:
    from testClass import testClass

```
print "Start"
proc_list = []
proc_list.append(testClass())
proc_list[-1].start()    

proc_list[-1].join()    

print "End"
```

This produces:

```
Start
__init__ PID: 89578
method1 PID: 89585
End
__del__ PID: 89578
0
```

Why it does not print `1`?

I'm guessing that it's related to the fact that `run` is actually being executed on a different process as can be seen. If this is the expected behavior how is everyone using multiprocessing where processes have an expensive `__init__` as in processes that need to open a database?

And shouldn't this behaviour be better highlighted in multiprocessing documentation?

Comment: Which line of code would you expect to print `1`?

Comment: print self.a from __del__. Run method set that to 1 but as you can see that is not propagated back to the destructor in python-multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your expensive initialization inside a context manager:

```
def run(self):
    with expensive_initialization() as initialized_object:
        do_some_logic_here(initialized_object)
```

You will have a chance to properly initialize your object before calling `do_some_logic_here`, and to properly release the resources after leaving the context manager's block.

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).

Comment: I could, but I ended up looking at this 'problem' because I wanted to add code at __del__ to ensure we properly closed down the database if something bad happened to the process or if a user didn't really use it as expected etc. Is there no other workaround here?

Comment: Using `__del__` doesn't really ensure the code there will be called when something bad happens. It's just a deconstructor. When something really bad happens your cleanup code might not even get any chance to be executed. If you want to provide this process class to users and make sure that they properly use the context manager, you can just create another stub method which should be overriden in subclasses (say `do` or `execute`) and call `self.do()` inside context manager inside `run`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `start()`, the interpreter forks and creates a child process, which gets a copy of the page tables from the parent. These point to pages which are marked as readonly and only copied when written (COW). The interpreter, when executing `run` in the child process, accesses the child's copy of the `PyObject` which represents `a`. The parent's memory is not touched. The child also gets a copy of the file descriptors table, which means that if a connection is opened by the parent, that file descriptor is inherited by the child. You can see (with `strace`) that the child is created via `clone` without `CLONE_FILES`:

```
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f460d8929d0)
```

Therefore, from clone man page:

> If CLONE_FILES is not set, the child process inherits a copy of all file descriptors opened in the calling process at the time of clone(). (The duplicated file descriptors in the child refer to the same open file descriptions (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptors in the calling process.) Subsequent operations that open or close file descriptors, or change file descriptor flags, performed by either the calling process or the child process do not affect the other process.